# remove / refactor to avoid N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into an issue where I'm having a massive N+1 issue with the following line:

```
<% @reports.each do |report| %>
  <% (@first_week..@current_week).each do |week_number| %>
    <% if report.user.answers.where(week_number: @current_week).exists? %>
        <%= image_tag report.user.avatar.url(:thumb), size: '30', class: 'img-circle media-object' %>
        <%= link_to "#{report.user.first_name + ' ' + report.user.last_name}", weekly_report_path(report.user.id, week_number) %>
        <%= report.user.due_date %>
        <%= week_number %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

as you see there is a ton of associations connected to each other, and I'm trying to find a way to simplify this.

The controller code is:

```
  def index
    @reports      = current_user.active_managements
    @current_week = Time.zone.now.strftime('%V').to_i
    @first_week   = current_user.created_at.strftime('%V').to_i
  end
```

how can I avoid an N+1 issue here, is the code fine and just needs to have eager loading or should I re-write - if so, any suggestions?

The bullet errors I get are:

```
  Reviewer => [:user]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:user]
  index:15 which is:
  <% if report.user.answers.where(week_number: @current_week).exists? %>



  User => [:company]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:company]
  navigation_links:21 which is:
<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_company_path(current_user.company) %></li>
```

for the line

Comment: Could you share your report and user model relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With limited information, I'll take a quick stab at it:

In your controller, you need to eager load users and their answers:

```
@reports = current_user.active_managements.includes(user: [:answers, :avatar] )
```

In the view, you would need to change your 'where' to a detect and loop through the eager loaded objects. NOTE: this isn't tested, and I'm just taking a stab at it. I hope it brings you down the right path:

```
<% @reports.each do |report| %>
  <% (@first_week..@current_week).each do |week_number| %>
    <% if report.user.answers.detect { |a| a.week_number == @current_week.to_s}.present? %>
        <%= image_tag report.user.avatar.url(:thumb), size: '30', class: 'img-circle media-object' %>
        <%= link_to "#{report.user.first_name + ' ' + report.user.last_name}", weekly_report_path(report.user.id, week_number) %>
        <%= report.user.due_date %>
        <%= week_number %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: would be nice to see a solution to the current_user.company issue as_well